# How to check directory exists in remote machine using Net::SSH2

Tags: perl

How are all here .... I need to check if there is any directory exists on a specified path. e.g.
if path is /root/home/
then check directory ABC if exists on this path.
I need if there is no such dir exists then create it else skip creating.

I am using `Net::SSH2`. I can create and save files using `Net::SSH2` but I don't know how to check the existence of directories and files using `Net::SSH2` in remote server.

[Net::SSH2](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aSSH2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::SSH2;
use Net::SSH2::SFTP;
use Net::SSH2::File;

my $host     = 'sftp.somesite.com';
my $path     = "/root/home/ABC";
my $user     = "user";
my $password = "passwd";

my $ssh = Net::SSH2->new();

die "Can't Connect to $host" unless $ssh->connect($host);

if ($ssh->auth_password($user, $password))
{
   my $sftp = $ssh->sftp();
   $sftp->opendir($path) or $sftp->mkdir($path);
   my $error = $sftp->error;
   print "Error: $error\n" if (!$sftp->opendir($path));
}
```

Comment: well thanks to help... I need to get error on creating directory if it throws any ... e.g. if permission is denied to create a directory or any other error when call $sftp->mkdir($path).... ?

Comment: ok ... well I used it... But I have felt that it does not show the true error. e.g. when I try to create directory using $sftp->mkdir($dir), and if this directory does not exist, it creates the directory but also print error: SSH_FX_NO_SUCH_FILE.... I dont know why this error throws....when not only the path is true but also the directory is created..

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're using the `sftp` method to create an [`Net::SSH2::SFTP`](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aSSH2%3a%3aSFTP) object?

What I would do is to call `Net::SSH2::SFTP->mkdir` method regardless of whether the directory exists: the overhead involved with attempting to create an already-existent directory is likely to be insignificant.

However if you *must* find whether a given directory is already in place, you can use the [`Net::SSH2::SFTP->opendir`](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aSSH2%3a%3aSFTP#opendir-dir-) method, which will return a valid [`Net::SSH2::Dir`](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aSSH2%3a%3aDir) object only if the directory exists.

Comment: Thanks dear. Now I am able to get whether the directory exists or not. I had been trying to resolve it for last 3 days. Thanks a lot.
Actually I am beginner and very new in perl.

Well one thing I want to ask by the way: What Net::SSH2::Dir object does in fact? Is this package contains any method? Because I cant see any method on the link you provided.

Comment: Glad you've found what you wanted. `Net::SSH2::Dir` has just one method called `read`. It is documented at that link. Once you have called `Net::SSH2::SFTP->opendir` to return a `Net::SSH2::Dir` object you should call `Net::SSH2::Dir->read` repeatedly to return each file in the directory. When there are no more files the methos returns `undef`.